# executing runOnUiThread on a separate class

Tags: java, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android how to runOnUiThread in other class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860384/android-how-to-runonuithread-in-other-class)

My Asyn Classes are a separate class file.

```
public class AdamTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
         public void showToast(final String toast)
        {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

How would I execute this method in my AsyncTask Class? I am getting an error The method `runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type AdamTask`

new AdamTask(Eve.this, `How to pass the eve activity here`).execute();

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to have the `Activity's` reference (lets name it `activity`) and pass it to your `AsyncTask` class. Then you can call `runOnUiThread` like this:

```
activity.runOnUiThread
```

The [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) is a method defined in `Activity` class.

Just add a contsructor to your AsyncTask. Your AsyncTask will look like this:

```
public class AdamTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

private Activity activity; //activity is defined as a global variable in your AsyncTask

public AdamTask(Activity activity) {

    this.activity = activity;
}

public void showToast(final String toast)
    {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run()
            {
                Toast.makeText(activity, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

...

}
```

Then to call the `AsyncTask` you need something like this:

```
AdamTask adamTask = new AdamTask(Eve.this);
adamTask.excecute(yourParams);
```

**UPDATE** As Sam mentioned in the comments, `AsyncTasks` may result in `context` leaking when configuration changes occur (one example is when screen rotates and the `Activity` is recreated). A way to deal with this is the [headless `fragment` technique](http://luboganev.github.io/blog/headless-fragments/).

Another way, more efficient, is using an event bus. See [here](http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/) for more information (link provided by Sam in the comments).

Comment: Hey you should probably mention the issues with leaking Activities from AsyncTasks

Comment: Brill, thanks. Another blog worth mentioning: http://simonvt.net/2014/04/17/asynctask-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/

Comment: @Sam Great! This is an even better solution.

Comment: Good Solution !

Answer (score 62):

Just typecast the context to Activity class

```
((Activity)context).runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        { 
             Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: save me from recreating  overloaded constructor hehe typecasting save me tnx bro!

Comment: It doesn't always work, you have to be sure that what you are casting is effectively an Activity or you'll have a ClassCastException.
 To do that you can do "if(context instanceOf Activity){ // proceed to cast }"

Comment: And the Kotlin version, 9 years later 

(context as Activity).runOnUiThread{
        Timber.d(gson.toJson(playlists))
}

Answer (score 4):

You need your Activity object to do this. Pass your Activity's this reference through the constructor and use it in your AsyncTask.

```
public class AdamTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
         public void showToast(final String toast)
        {
            activityObj.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Since runOnUiThread is a public method in Activity class, you cannot use it in some other Custom class or class that extends other than Activity itself.

Look here, [runonUi.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

If you are not clear, please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7887189/603744) to learn how to send Activity Object through constructor