# Not able to call runOnUiThread in a thread from inside of a service

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I wanted to make a service which will check my SMS in every 20 sec if there are any unread SMS then send it to my website then mark as read for posting data to website I used asynctask and it worked fine when I tried manually (by making button click type app)
but in side service I cant define

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { new MyAsyncTask().execute(sender,time,message);}
        });
```

it is unable to identify and asks me to define runOnUiThread
Is there any way to call my asynctask from the place where I am calling in below code

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    String sender = null;
    String time = null;
    String message = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Created", 1).show();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Destroy", 1).show();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service Running ", 1).show();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                Uri mSmsinboxQueryUri = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
                String[] columns = new String[] { "_id", "thread_id",
                        "address", "person", "date", "body", "type" };
                Cursor cursor1 = getContentResolver().query(mSmsinboxQueryUri,
                    null, "read=0", null, null);
                DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                    "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss.SSS");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                if (cursor1.getCount() > 0) {
                    cursor1.moveToFirst();
                    do {
                        // Retrieving sender number
                        sender = (cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[2])).toString());
                        // Retriving time of reception
                        long ms = cursor1.getLong(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[4]));
                        calendar.setTimeInMillis(ms);
                        time = formatter.format(calendar.getTime()).toString();
                        // Retriving the message body
                        message = (cursor1.getString(cursor1
                            .getColumnIndex(columns[5])).toString());
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                new MyAsyncTask()
                                    .execute(sender, time, message);
                            }
                        });
                    } while (cursor1.moveToNext());// end of while
                }// end of if
                    // set as read
                values.put("read", true);
                getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"),
                    values, null, null);
            }
        }).start();
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double> {

        @Override
        protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {
            postData(params[0], params[1], params[2]);
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Double result) {
            // pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "command sent",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
            // pb.setProgress(progress[0]);
        }

        public void postData(String sender, String time, String message) {
            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                "http://www.mysite.co.nf/reciever.php");
            try {
                // Add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = 
                                                new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sender", sender));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("time", time));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", message));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {} catch (IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28873148/2670370 This answer might be helpful

Comment: A Service has no UI-Thread because a Service has no UI. I think this is the (good) reason behind the missing runOnUiThread function. 
You have to run your code on the Services Mainthread.

Answer (score 58):

`Service` does not have a method called `runOnUiThread()`. You're assuming that the method from `Activity` is also defined for a `Service`, but it's not.

Solution, just define a method that does exactly that.  Here's a simplified example, the rest of your code would remain unchanged.

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class TestService extends Service {

    Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // Handler will get associated with the current thread, 
        // which is the main thread.
        handler = new Handler();
        super.onCreate();
    }

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable runnable) {
        handler.post(runnable);
    }

}
```

For more info, [see the docs for Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). It's used to dump some work onto a specific thread.  In this case, the `Handler` gets associated with the UI thread, since the UI thread always calls `Service.onCreate()`.

Comment: unnable to define like this it shows error 

*Cannot instantiate the type Handler*

when I write `handler = new Handler();` in onCreate

Comment: Make sure you have `import android.os.Handler;`

Comment: I have imported it ,checked it .Even if I wouldn't have done it suggests to import

Comment: You'll have to be more specific, or update your question.  That compiles fine for me.

Comment: @AmitSwain: you are not running this in the UI thread -  wsanville : `new Thread(new Runnable() {run(){runOnUiThread()});` - no Looper - boom

Comment: @wsanville: you are right - I thought he was calling this from a non UI thread - which he probably does anyway

Comment: Superb Man. Great answer. Would be much better if you explain it in a bit detail for a beginner like me.