# RuntimeException creating a WebView dynamically in Android O

Tags: android, webview

I'm creating a Webview dynamically from an `IntentService` in Android O, and getting the following crash:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
 at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:353)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Did not yet override the UI thread
 at org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.getUiThreadHandler(ThreadUtils.java:5)
 at org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.runningOnUiThread(ThreadUtils.java:45)
 at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.C(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:149)
 at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.l(WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.java:262)
 at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromium.init(WebViewChromium.java:29)
 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:658)
 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:588)
 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:571)
 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:558)
 at android.webkit.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:548)`

This used to work fine with earlier versions of Android. Any ideas?

Comment: As the message indicates there is some problem with a class that is interacting with the UI thread.  I have seen similar problems in the past and worked around them by doing all WebView interactions on the UI thread.  In your service, can you try the following: `context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {public void run() { /* your code here */ }});`  (replace /*your code here*/ with the code that creates the WebView.)
`

Comment: Unfortunately `runOnUiThread` is a method of `Activity` not `Context`, which is not relevant in the context of a service.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948251/not-able-to-call-runonuithread-in-a-thread-from-inside-of-a-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @EJK mentioned, the solution was to run the problematic code on the UI thread. I achieved that by switching from an IntentService to a Service.