# Android Fragment Animation for custom views

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-animation

I can't seem to find an answer for my question on google or SO so let me try to explain it properly.

I have A Main Activity, which creates a Custom Fragment. This CustomFragment then contains several Custom "extended" Buttons (views) in which An ObjectAnimator is applied to them.

That ObjectAnimator does not update on the main thread (I'm assuming), even though isRunning() returns true. ObjectAnimator works perfectly fine inside of the CustomFragment, but when using it inside of the Extended Button class, it fails.

I'm thinking I need to be using runOnUiThread() or some other way to get it to run on the proper thread, but I haven't been able to find a good solution.

Here's some psuedocode:

```
public class TestButton extends Button{
    private AnimatorSet as;

    public TestButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "alpha", 0.2f, 1.0f);
        as = new AnimatorSet();
        as.play(alphaAnimator);
        as.setDuration(1000);
    }

    public void startAnimation(){
        as.start();
        //tried adding invalidate(); here but that didn't seem to fix it either
    }
}

public class CustomFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment implements Runnable {

    private View root;
    private ArrayList<TestButton> buttons;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, bundle SavedInstanceState){
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraglayout, container, false);

        initButtons();
        return view;
    }

    private void initButtons(){
        buttons = new ArrayList<TestButton>();
        //Code here to initialize and find the buttons in the layout, this works properly
        //so I won't define it here because it is long, the list does contain its members
        //
    }

    private void startTest(View view){
        //An actual "Button" controls this, and is called properly

        //THE FOLLOWING WORKS PERFECTLY FINE
        ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "alpha", 0.2f, 1.0f);
        alphaAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        alphaAnimator.start();

        //THIS DOES NOT WORK AT ALL, JUST CHANGES THE VIEW ONCE BUT ANIMATION DOESNT 'RUN'
        for(TestButton b : buttons){
            b.startAnimation();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        root.postDelayed(this,1000);
    }
}
```

It must be something with the threading, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

--- Edit ---
Okay, So I was just messing around with the thread and added a simple boolean to test whether or not to start the animations in the Fragment's Run() function. And it does work for animation, however this doesn't seem like the proper way to do it because I'm gonna have tons of booleans to check so there must be some other way to run a function on a thread, going back to runOnUiThread() But I'm not sure how to use it. This is what I did that works in premise, but isn't proper programming.

```
private void startTest(View view){
        tester = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        if(tester){
            for(TestButton b : buttons)
               b.startAnimation();
            tester = false;
        }
        root.postDelayed(this,1000);
    }
```

--- Edit 2 ---
[This seems to work, and helped me out.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860384/android-how-to-runonuithread-in-other-class) If anyone else needs this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

[Following this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7860384/android-how-to-runonuithread-in-other-class), this seems to work perfectly.

```
public class TestButton extends Button{
    private AnimatorSet as;
    private Handler handler;

    public TestButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        handler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
        init();
    }

    private void init(){
        //Does get called properly

        ObjectAnimator alphaAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "alpha", 0.2f, 1.0f);
        as = new AnimatorSet();
        as.play(alphaAnimator);
        as.setDuration(1000);
    }

    public void startAnimation(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                as.start();
            }
        });
        as.start();
    }

    private void runOnUiThread(Runnable r){
        handler.post(r);
    }
}
```